# 前月・翌月へのリンクが上手く表示されません。

Tags: php

ドットインストールでカレンダーのアプリケーションを作成しています。

http://dotinstall.com/lessons/calendar_php_v3/34311

月の左右にある「<<」「>>」のリンク先が先月・翌月のカレンダーにリンクするはずですが、
なぜかxamppのdashboadのページへ飛ばされます。。。

基本的にソースは記載されているものと照らし合わせているので
エラーがあるわけではないですが、理由が分からず手が止まっています。

どなたか教えてください><

一応、自身のソースは下記に転記いたします。

```
<?php

function h($s) {
  return htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

try {
  if (!isset($_GET['t']) || !preg_match('/\A\d{4}-\d{2}\z/', $_GET['t'])) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
  $thisMonth = new DateTime($_GET['t']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $thisMonth = new DateTime('first day of this month');
}

//var_dump($thisMonth);
//exit;

$dt = clone $thisMonth;
$prev = $dt->modify('-1 month')->format('Y-m');
$dt = clone $thisMonth;
$next = $dt->modify('+1 month')->format('Y-m');


$yearMonth= $thisMonth->format('F Y'); //Fは月、Yは年

//前月のカレンダーを表示
$tail = '';
$lastDayOfPrevMonth = new DateTime('last day of '.$yearMonth. ' -1 month');
while ($lastDayOfPrevMonth->format('w') < 6) {
  $tail = sprintf('<td class="gray">%d</td>', $lastDayOfPrevMonth->format('d')) . $tail;
  $lastDayOfPrevMonth->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

$body = '';
$period = new DatePeriod(
  new DateTime('first day of' .$yearMonth), //今月の最初の日を取得
  new DateInterval('P1D'), //1日ずつ取得
  new DateTime('first day of '.$yearMonth. ' +1 month') //今月の最後の日を取得
);

$today = new DateTime('today');

//今月のカレンダーを表示
foreach ($period as $day) {
  if ($day->format('w') % 7 === 0) { //$day->format('w') で日曜日が0、月曜日が1といった具合に表現できる。それを7で割る
    $body .= '</tr><tr>';
  }
  $todayClass = ($day->format('Y-m-d') === $today->format('Y-m-d')) ? 'today' : '';
  $body .= sprintf('<td class="youbi_%d %s">%d</td>', $day->format('w'), $todayClass, $day->format('d')); //日を2桁の数字で表す
}

//来月1ヶ月のカレンダーを表示
$head = '';
$firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime('first day of '.$yearMonth. ' +1 month'); //来月初日を$firstDayOfNextMonthに格納
while ($firstDayOfNextMonth->format('w') > 0) { //来月初日が0より大きければ
  $head .= sprintf('<td class="gray">%d</td>', $firstDayOfNextMonth->format('d')); //グレイ色にすし2桁の数字で表示する
  $firstDayOfNextMonth->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

$html = '<tr>'. $tail . $body . $head . '</tr>';

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="/?t=<?php echo h($prev); ?>">&laquo;</a></th>
        <th colspan="5"><?php echo $yearMonth; ?></th>
        <th><a href="/?=<?php echo h($next); ?>">&raquo;</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Sun</td>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thu</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="7"><a href="/">Today</a></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
function connectDb(){
  try {
    return new PDO(DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
}

function h($s){
  return htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

?>
```

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

table {
  margin: 15px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}

th, td{
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

.youbi_0 {
  color: red;
}

.youbi_6 {
  color: blue;
}

.today {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gray {
  color: #dedede;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<th><a href="/?t=<?php echo h($prev); ?>">&laquo;</a></th>
```

このURLであれば、ファイル名がindex.php(一般的な環境の場合)である必要がありますが、別のファイル名になっていませんか。

たとえばこのファイルが`calendar.php`だとするとリンクをたどるとサーバのデフォルトのページが表示されるでしょう。

あとは余談ですが、

```
<th><a href="/?=<?php echo h($next); ?>">&raquo;</a></th>
```

パラメータの`t`が抜けているように見えます。

またこのコード細かくは追いかけていませんがどこかで無限ループしているような気がします。